# Java basic if/else statement state change

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, actionlistener, jlabel

please see my attached code below and then my question at the end.

```
class events extends JFrame{
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

    public events() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        button = new JButton("Click for text");
        add(button);

        label = new JLabel("");
        add(label);

        event e = new event();
        button.addActionListener(e);

    }

    public class event implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int x = 0;
            if (x == 0) {

                label.setText("the new label");
                System.out
                        .println("setting x to 0 and label to display a label");
                x = 1;
                System.out.println(x);
            } else {
                label.setText("newerer label");
                System.out.println("i reached the else segment");

                x = 0;
                System.out.println(x);
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        events gui = new events();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setTitle("Events Test");
        gui.setSize(300, 100);
        gui.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Background:  I am learning java and attempting to understand a concept.  With this program I was attempting to create a small gui with a button that when clicked would assign a JLabel the String value of "the new label."  I wanted to use that same button however to change the label to "newerer label" if clicked a second time and back again if clicked a third.  I attempted to do this using an If/ Else statement with a variable x to hold essentially a state of 1 or 0.  At the end of each portion of the If/Else i change the state of x to either 1 or 0 appropriately.  When attempting to run the program in eclipse however, I have run into some kind of error.  I assigned a system.out.println to each portion of the If/Else in an attempt to see how the program switches between the two states but it appears that my else statement is never reached.

Questions:

1. Is an If/Else statement appropriate to perform such a simple 2 state switch?
2. Is there a more appropriate way to do this? (i know about switch statements but opted for this as it was only a two state project).
3. What did I do wrong and why is my Else path never achieved when the state should be 1?

Thank you for your responses,
Pano

Comment: you see that you always will hit the first if ( x == 0 ), as you just before set the x to 0.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind , +1 for keen examination!

Comment: That's a huge amount of code. You should edit down your code samples to only include what's relevant to your question. (Very often input/output/GUI code.)

Comment: @millimoose, is it not appropriate to display the whole code?  as per Mr.D's response, another observer might not have known where in my code it may be more appropriate to declare x.  If that is not the case then I apologize and will not do this again.  This is my first post after all.

Comment: @Warmonger0 did you get it resolved?

Comment: @Warmonger0 For Mr.D to give his answer it would've sufficed to know that `x` is a local variable of the method, and it doesn't matter for the purposes of your question that you're using Swing - the `println()` calls are sufficient output to be able to say "after clicking the button four times, XXXX is printed, when I wanted XYXY". Also, the process of trying to trim your problem down to the bare essentials can often help you solve it - the irrelevant code is as much an impediment to you as to other SO users.

Comment: @Warmonger0 Furthermore, it also harms reproducibility. A notorious example are homework assignment questions where the program is required to accept input in some predefined ad-hoc format. Now, you can't just copy-paste the code sample and run it and see the problem, you have to do that, then run it, then copy-paste the input data into a terminal, and that's a whole other thing that's additional effort. Generally, the chance of a question getting answered quickly is higher the less effort it takes to provide the answer.

Comment: i did get it resolved thank you to everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable "x" must be declared as a class member.

```
public class event implements ActionListener{
    private int x = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(x == 0){
            label.setText("the new label");
            System.out.println("setting x to 0 and label to display a label");
            x = 1;
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        else {
            label.setText("newerer label");
            System.out.println("i reached the else segment");
            x = 0;
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing `x` every time the action listener gets called, so `x` is always 0. Move `x` somewhere else, possibly declare it as a class member.

Comment: okay, i understand your comment Mr. D where you say i am initilizing x every time the action listener gets called.  would be it appropriate to declare it after JButton as a private variable?

Comment: actually no, you wouldn't be able to access it if you declare it private in another class

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, I personally would use an if/else statement here, although if you are likely to add more states a switch statement *may* be appropriate, but I think given you have more than 1 line of code in the if/else blocks I would keep it as if/else as it has better readability in my experience.
2. I guess my answer to 1 covers this!
3. The reason your else block isn't being reached is that your x variable is only in scope (only exists) inside that method. As soon as you leave the method the value is no longer in scope so as far as your code in concerned it no longer exists. The code P Lalonde posted shows the correct way: having the variable as a member variable (object scope). Read more about member variable scope here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a switch of state you could actually do something like:

```
if( label.getText().equals("the new label") ) {
  label.setText("newerer label");
} else {
  label.setText("the new label");
}
```

Comment: Ugh, no. Application state should be abstract and separate from what's displayed in the GUI.